# How can I add FLAC files to my iTunes library on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, flac

I want to add FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec) files on my iTunes Library. I googled on how to do so, and found Fluke for Mac, which looks great, except that I don't have a Mac. I have iTunes 9 on Win7.

So, aside from converting FLAC files to other formats or switching to a Mac, what else can I do to add the files to my library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is currently no way to do this in Windows.  Even if you could add the FLAC file to your iTunes library, it would not be possible to play them on your iPod / iPhone anyway.

I suggest that you look into alternative media players such as Winamp and MediaMonkey.  Both work with FLAC [out of the box](http://flac.sourceforge.net/documentation_tasks.html).

For a full list of supported players, see the 'Comparison' page on the above website.

Comment: +1 for alternative solutions.  **Apple sucks**, especially at playing nicely with anything they didn't create.

Answer (score 4):

[Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) (warning: hard to set up), [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/), and [J River Media Center](http://www.jrmediacenter.com/) (warning: not free) are all programs I would recommend to someone coming from iTunes if you want to switch player.

If you want to stick to iTunes, your best option is to convert the files to [ALAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless) (Apple Lossless Audio Codec), which works in iTunes and on iPods. This is a lossless->lossless conversion so you lose nothing. [Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/) and [DBPowerAmp](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/) (warning: not free) would be good choices for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not command-line averse, check out my first iTunes for Windows automation [script](http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/small-hacks/itunes-automation-convert-flac-audio-files-to-apple-lossless/). It batch imports all FLAC files in and below the given folder into iTunes in ALAC format, preserving album, artist, and song name. (If track number, genre and/or year are present in the FLAC file, they are preserved too.)

The script is totally free and open-source (MIT license); you can [fork](https://github.com/dmitryleskov/iTunesScripts) it on GitHub if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Foobar2000 is the bee's knees, but [AIMP](http://www.aimp2.us/aimp3-download.php) isn't far behind. If you used Winamp before, you won't have a problem getting used to it.